# Cannot cast MediaPlayerController to music player - getting exception

Tags: android, audio-player, mediacontroller, android-music-player

Hello I've tried to use media player controller in my music player app, but when I use musicplayer.setMediaPlayer I got an exception. Here is my snippet of the code and logcat error.

```
musicPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MusicPlayer.this, uri);
        musicPlayer.setWakeMode(this.getApplicationContext(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
        MediaController musicControl = new MediaController(this);
        musicControl.show();
        musicControl.setMediaPlayer((MediaPlayerControl) musicPlayer);
        musicPlayer.start();
```

and this is logcat

```
Process: com.tproductions.Openit, PID: 11382
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tproductions.Openit/com.tproductions.Openit.MusicPlayer}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.media.MediaPlayer cannot be cast to android.widget.MediaController$MediaPlayerControl
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2286)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1246)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5135)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:877)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.media.MediaPlayer cannot be cast to android.widget.MediaController$MediaPlayerControl
        at com.tproductions.Openit.MusicPlayer.onCreate(MusicPlayer.java:49)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
```

any ideas how can I solve this ? Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `MediaPlayer` doesn't implement `MediaController.MediaPlayerControl`.

You have two choices that I can think of...

First choice is to extend `MediaPlayer` and implement the interface. Example...

```
public class MyMediaPlayer extends MediaPlayer
    implements MediaController.MediaPlayerControl {

    ...

}
```

...that would allow you to use an instance of `MyMediaPlayer` in the call to `musicControl.setMediaPlayer(...)`.

Alternatively, just implement the interface on your `Activity`. Example...

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity
    implements MediaController.MediaPlayerControl {

    ...

}
```

When you call `musicControl.setMediaPlayer(...)` in your `Activity` you would simply pass `this` as the parameter.